# Absolute positioned element inside of table cell with variable height

Tags: css, html-table, css-position

There are quite a number of questions here on stackexchange on the absolute positioning inside TD, but I didn't find solution for my specific issue:

I need to implement following layout
[image: layout of elements inside TD]

This cell is part of tabular data representation in table.

Content of the cell is text data.

Text can be multi-line and has to be vertically and horizontally center aligned. **Height of cell may vary** as table row height may be stretched by other cells' content, but cell text should always stay vertically aligned (currently it's achieved by `vertical-align: middle`)

Absolutely positioned element should always reside in the top-right corner of the cell.

I know about technics of placing relative div inside TD and then placing absolute positioned element inside div, but due to variable cell height and requirement of vertical-aligned cell text it seems not an option.

Solution need to be compatible with IE8+, Chrome 21+ and FF 15+

Comment: you can't use position in td. you have to put a div inside the td and then make de positioning

Answer (score 1):

Insert a div around your closebutton:

```
<table>
    <tr>
       <td>
          <div class="wrapper">
              <div class="close">X</div>
          </div>
          My vertically aligned text.
       </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

And then position your closebutton:

```
table td div.wrapper {
    position: relative;
}

table td div.close {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
}
```